# Django: Form that on submit updates a status message on the view and downloads a file

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a view that shows: status message, text field, submit button

Selecting submit can succeed or fail

For successful requests, I want to download a file and update the status message ("success") on the view. On failure, I want to just update the view's status message ("failed").

```
def download_file(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context['message'] = ''

    filename = request.POST.get('filename')
    data = get_file(filename)

    if data:
        response = HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/octet-stream")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="download.bin"'
        return response   # NOT the desired behavior, this will only download the file, not update the view
    else:
        context['message'] = "failed"
        return render_to_response('download_page.html', context_instance=context)
```

download_page.html

```
<label>status: {{ message }}</label>
<form action="/download/" method="post"> 
    <label>filename: </label>
    <input id="filename" type="text" name="filename">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use django embed forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.9/topics/forms/)
In your form, you'll just have to define a "clean_filename" function that will raise an error is the file isn't found.

You could display your "message" in your template.

Try with:

```
{{ message }}
<form action="/download/" method="post">
    <label>filename: </label>
    <input id="filename" type="text" name="filename">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I would not recommand that.
The first solution, is more pythonic and re-usable.